# Redirect to another Node.js page after a period of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I wanted to know if there's a way to render a page in Node.js and then after 2 seconds redirect to another page. Something among the lines :

```
app.get('/thankyou',function(req,res){
    res.render('thankyou' {message : 'Thank you for your submission'});

    //after 2 seconds

    res.redirect('nextpage');
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to do it in the template. The server code becomes:

```
app.get('/thankyou',function(req,res){
    res.render('thankyou' {message : 'Thank you for your submission'});
});
```

And in the template add:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function () {
     // after 2 seconds
     window.location = "/next-page";
  }, 2000)
</script>
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!